# Play 2.5 with Silhouette 4.0 - Credential Provider

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I am trying to write a sample app with Play 2.5 using Silhouette 4.0 for user/password authentication.

Source code available at : https://github.com/pariksheet/dribble

I am stuck at setting requestProvider in Environment object

```
Environment[JWTEnv](
  identityService,
  authenticatorService,
  Seq(),
  eventBus
)
```

As I am not able to figure out the solution,  I am injecting Credential Provider in my all controller classes.

```
    class MyController @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi,val silhouette: Silhouette[JWTEnv],
  authInfoRepository: AuthInfoRepository,
  credentialsProvider: CredentialsProvider)
    extends Controller {
          def authenticate = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
        credentialsProvider.authenticate(Credentials(data.email, data.password)).flatMap { loginInfo => ..}    
         //   silhouette.env.requestProviders.foreach { x => println("====" + x.id) }  --- I am hoping to get credential provider from silhouette object

        ...
        ...
        }
    }
```

My Module.scala as below -

```
package module

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.Provides
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Env
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.EventBus
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Silhouette
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.SilhouetteProvider
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.crypto.Base64AuthenticatorEncoder
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.repositories.AuthInfoRepository
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.services.AuthenticatorService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.services.AvatarService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.services.IdentityService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.CacheLayer
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.Clock
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.FingerprintGenerator
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.HTTPLayer
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.IDGenerator
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.PasswordHasher
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.PasswordHasherRegistry
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.PasswordInfo
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.PlayHTTPLayer
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.JWTAuthenticator
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.JWTAuthenticatorService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.JWTAuthenticatorSettings
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers.CredentialsProvider
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.services.GravatarService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.util.DefaultFingerprintGenerator
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.util.PlayCacheLayer
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.util.SecureRandomIDGenerator
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.password.BCryptPasswordHasher
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.persistence.daos.DelegableAuthInfoDAO
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.persistence.repositories.DelegableAuthInfoRepository

import daos.MongoUserDao
import daos.MongoUserTokenDao
import daos.PasswordInfoDao
import daos.UserDao
import daos.UserTokenDao
import models.User
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import services.UserService

trait JWTEnv extends Env {
  type I = User
  type A = JWTAuthenticator
}

class Module extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  def configure() {
    bind[IdentityService[User]].to[UserService]
    bind[UserDao].to[MongoUserDao]
    bind[UserTokenDao].to[MongoUserTokenDao]
    bind[DelegableAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo]].to[PasswordInfoDao]
    bind[IDGenerator].toInstance(new SecureRandomIDGenerator())
    bind[PasswordHasher].toInstance(new BCryptPasswordHasher)
    bind[FingerprintGenerator].toInstance(new DefaultFingerprintGenerator(false))
    bind[EventBus].toInstance(EventBus())
    bind[Clock].toInstance(Clock())
    bind[CacheLayer].to[PlayCacheLayer]
    bind[Silhouette[JWTEnv]].to[SilhouetteProvider[JWTEnv]]
  }

  @Provides
  def provideHTTPLayer(client: WSClient): HTTPLayer = new PlayHTTPLayer(client)

  @Provides
  def provideEnvironment(
    identityService: IdentityService[User],
    authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[JWTAuthenticator],
    eventBus: EventBus): Environment[JWTEnv] = {

    Environment[JWTEnv](
      identityService,
      authenticatorService,
      Seq(),
      eventBus
    )
  }

  @Provides
  def provideAuthenticatorService(
    fingerprintGenerator: FingerprintGenerator,
    idGenerator: IDGenerator,
    configuration: Configuration,
    clock: Clock): AuthenticatorService[JWTAuthenticator] = {
    val settings = JWTAuthenticatorSettings(
      sharedSecret = configuration.getString("application.secret").getOrElse("PARI"))


    new JWTAuthenticatorService(
      settings = settings,
      repository = None,
      authenticatorEncoder = new Base64AuthenticatorEncoder,
      idGenerator = idGenerator,
      clock = Clock())
  }

  @Provides
  def provideAuthInfoRepository(
    passwordInfoDAO: DelegableAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo]): AuthInfoRepository = {

    new DelegableAuthInfoRepository(passwordInfoDAO)
  }

  @Provides
  def providePasswordHasherRegistry(passwordHasher: PasswordHasher): PasswordHasherRegistry = {
    new PasswordHasherRegistry(passwordHasher)
  }

  @Provides
  def provideCredentialsProvider(
    authInfoRepository: AuthInfoRepository,
    passwordHasherRegistry: PasswordHasherRegistry): CredentialsProvider = {

    new CredentialsProvider(authInfoRepository, passwordHasherRegistry)
  }


  @Provides
  def provideAvatarService(httpLayer: HTTPLayer): AvatarService = new GravatarService(httpLayer)

}
```

Can you please help me over here?

Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two different things here. The credentials provider is not a request provider. A request provider is a special type of provider, which can be directly hooked into the request. A detailed description can be found in the [documentation](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/providers#request-providers). Silhouette provides a [Basic Authentication provider](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/providers#basic-authentication-provider) which is an implementation of a request provider.

The credentials provider should directly injected into your controller as implemented in the [seed template](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/app/controllers/SignInController.scala#L43).

Comment: Thanks for info. I guess, I need to read request provider more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

The request providers are set in your Module.scala, but they are set to an empty Sequence:

```
@Provides
def provideEnvironment(
  identityService: IdentityService[User],
  authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[JWTAuthenticator],
  eventBus: EventBus): Environment[JWTEnv] = {

  Environment[JWTEnv](
    identityService,
    authenticatorService,
    Seq(),                 // Here the request providers are set
    eventBus
  )
}
```

Ps: Keep in mind, that the `foreach` will always "return none", since its type is `unit`

Comment: Thanks Moritz. I have figured it out later. I have Injected val credentialsProvider: CredentialsProvider , explicitly in controller. I am able to use credential provider now. 

Not sure how to set in Environment. What is the code instead of Seq().

Any idea.
Thanks

Comment: @Moritz - Could you please help me with doing something similar but for compile time injection. The SO issue is created at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586114/unable-to-create-environment-in-silhouette