# unable to create `Environment` in `Silhouette`

Tags: silhouette

I am trying to create the `Environment` in `Silhouette` but am unable to. I have defined the `Identity` and `Authenticator` as follows

```
trait SessionEnv extends Env {
  type I = User
  type A = SessionAuthenticator
}
```

Next, I suppose I have to create the `Environment`. For that I have written the following code but am stick as I do not understand how to pass the different parameters expected by `Environment`'s `apply` method

Environment companion object's apply method has signature

```
   def apply[E <: Env](
  identityServiceImpl: IdentityService[E#I],
  authenticatorServiceImpl: AuthenticatorService[E#A],
  requestProvidersImpl: Seq[RequestProvider],
  eventBusImpl: EventBus
```

I know that I have to provide the implemention of `IdentityService`. I have done so as follows

```
class UserService @Inject()(userDao:UsersRepository) extends IdentityService[User] {...}
```

User is defined as follows

```
case class UserProfile(
                    loginInfo:LoginInfo,
                    confirmed: Boolean,
                    email:Option[String],
                    firstName: Option[String],
                    lastName: Option[String],
                    passwordInfo:Option[PasswordInfo]
                    //oauth1Info: Option[OAuth1Info],
                    //avatarUrl: Option[String]) {
                  )

//representation of a user. A user has an Id and a profile
case class User (id:UUID, profile:UserProfile)
```

But what do I pass for other values required by apply -  authenticatorServiceImpl: AuthenticatorService[E#A],
      requestProvidersImpl: Seq[RequestProvider],
      eventBusImpl: EventBus

```
val sessionEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[SessionEnv](new UserService(userRepository),????)
```

Also, I suppose I don't have to use `Guice` as I am using compile time injection. Is that correct?

UPDATE
I changed from `SessionAuthenticatorService` to `CookieAuthenticatorService` to try some code available online.

It seems my understanding that `Silhouette` provides some default implementations isn't exactly correct. I thought that I could simply use the `SessionAuthenticatorService` companion object defined in `https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/authenticators/SessionAuthenticator.scala` but that is not the case. Looking at some code created in `ScalaModule`, it seems that I'll have to create the required object myself but I'll need to do it in my AppLoader class (for compile time DI) instead of ScalaModule (for runtime DI). However, I still have not solved the problem. I do not know how to create the `signer` required by `CookieAuthenticatorService`

```
val config = configuration.underlying.asInstanceOf[CookieAuthenticatorSettings]("silhouette.authenticator")
  val fingerprintGenerator = new DefaultFingerprintGenerator(false)
  val idGenerator = new SecureRandomIDGenerator()
  val clock:Clock = Clock()

  val authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[CookieAuthenticator] = new CookieAuthenticatorService(config,None,,,fingerprintGenerator, idGenerator,clock) //STILL NEED TO FIND OUT HOW TO CREATE Signer AND CookieHeaderEncoding required by CookieAuthenticator service


 val cookieEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[CookieEnv](userIdentityService ,authenticatorService,Seq(),EventBus())
```

Comment: I suppose Silhouette provides default implementations for Authenticators, Providers and we can also get reference to the event bus. I tried `val sessionEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[SessionEnv](new UserService(userRepository),SessionAuthenticatorService() ,CredentialsProvider(),EventBus())` but I get error `om.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.SessionAuthenticatorService.type does not take parameters`. I removed the `()` but got error `found   : SessionAuthenticatorService.type
[error]  required: AuthenticatorService[components.SessionEnv#A]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation for cookie authenticator

```
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions._
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.{EventBus, SilhouetteProvider}

import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.crypto.CrypterAuthenticatorEncoder
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.Clock
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.crypto.{JcaCrypter, JcaCrypterSettings, JcaSigner, JcaSignerSettings}
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.{CookieAuthenticatorService, CookieAuthenticatorSettings}
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.util.{DefaultFingerprintGenerator, SecureRandomIDGenerator}
import components._
import play.api.mvc.DefaultCookieHeaderEncoding
import controllers._
import play.api._
import services.db.cassandra.UserService
import play.filters.csrf._
import services.AtomicCounter
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents
import router.Routes


class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
      _.configure(context.environment, context.initialConfiguration, Map.empty)
    }
    new AppComponents(context).application
  }
}

class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with CassandraRepositoryComponents
  with HttpFiltersComponents
  with AssetsComponents
  with CSRFComponents
  /*with SilhouetteComponents*/{ //TODOM - Would prefer SilhouetteComponent but creating an Environment requires IdentityService.  UserService is an IdentifyService but it requires userRepository which is created here. Need to resolve this cross dependence

  val userIdentityService = new UserService(userRepository) //responsible for retrieving user information (eg email id) from a database

  val config =  CookieAuthenticatorSettings() 
  val fingerprintGenerator = new DefaultFingerprintGenerator(false)
  val idGenerator = new SecureRandomIDGenerator()
  val clock:Clock = Clock()
  val signer= new JcaSigner(new JcaSignerSettings("someSigner"))
  val crypter = new JcaCrypter(new JcaCrypterSettings("someCrypter"))
  val authenticatorEncoder = new CrypterAuthenticatorEncoder(crypter)
  val cookieHeaderEncoding= new DefaultCookieHeaderEncoding()
  val authenticatorService = new CookieAuthenticatorService(config, None, signer, cookieHeaderEncoding, authenticatorEncoder, fingerprintGenerator, idGenerator, clock)

  val cookieEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[CookieEnv](userIdentityService ,authenticatorService,Seq(),EventBus())

  val defaultParser = new mvc.BodyParsers.Default()

  val securedAction = new DefaultSecuredAction(new DefaultSecuredRequestHandler(new DefaultSecuredErrorHandler(messagesApi)), defaultParser )
  val unsecuredAction = new DefaultUnsecuredAction(new DefaultUnsecuredRequestHandler(new DefaultUnsecuredErrorHandler(messagesApi)),defaultParser)
  val userAware = new DefaultUserAwareAction(new DefaultUserAwareRequestHandler(),defaultParser)

  val silhouette = new SilhouetteProvider[CookieEnv](cookieEnv,securedAction,unsecuredAction,userAware)
  lazy val userRepositoryController = new UserController(userRepository, controllerComponents)
  lazy val homeController = new HomeController(controllerComponents, csrfAddToken,csrfCheck,silhouette) //using Silhouette in only one controller for the moment

  lazy val countController = new CountController(controllerComponents,new AtomicCounter())
  lazy val asyncController = new AsyncController(controllerComponents, actorSystem)

  lazy val userWSRoutes = new WSRouters.User.UserRouter(userRepositoryController) //TODOM - whatam i doing here?

  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController,userWSRoutes, countController,asyncController, assets)

}
```